# AngularJS : directive on a DOM element not present on page load doesn't compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a new directive ngModelOnblur from one of the examples at SO which makes ng-model only listen to blur events on input elements. The directive works fine when the element is present on page load. I want to use the same directive on one of the input elements on a different page where the element is not present on page load but is added when an AJAX call finishes.

The template looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="person.city" ng-model-onblur ng-change="validateCity(person.city)" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's how the directive looks:

```
angular.directive('ngModelOnblur', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority: 1, //this is required for the directive to run after ng-model is compiled.
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (attr.type === 'radio' || attr.type === 'checkbox') return;

            elm.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                });
            });
    }
  };
});
```

I've tried using $timeout and scope.$evalAsync in the link function but nothing seems to trigger the directive compilation.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how are you injecting the new html? You probably will have to compile it

Comment: persons is null initially but is added after an AJAX call finishes.

Comment: that comment is meaningless. How is added code wise?

Comment: I meant the element is hidden on page load because persons array is empty.

Comment: create a demo in plunker, the lack of details in your comments isn't helping

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the template using `ng-view`? 
Is the link function being called at all?

If you are loading the template through some other means, you may need to manually [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) the html.

```
var html = $(someDomNode).html();
$compile(html)(scope);
```

Comment: I'm not using ng-view. persons is null initially but is added after an AJAX call finishes. the link function is not being called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I think I might have made a stupid mistake. I added my new directive in a separate module but didn't add the dependency in my original module. I'll try that and see if it works.
Sorry for the confusion and thanks @charlietfl and @agreco. I'll ask again if after adding the dependency it doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Turns out that was the problem. The directive is working when the element is visible after AJAX call finishes, during initial load and all the different cases. Thanks for all your help and sorry for the confusion. It would be helpful if angular could give more explanation of the problem.